# Handling exceptions - Enough to ensure return value

Tags: exception

I have seen others write that if you don't do something with the exception then don't bother catching it. I can see point in that but what I am wondering is what entails "doing something with the exception"?

Does logging the error count as enough? I have some code where I want to return null if anything goes wrong. Is that reason enough to catch an exception?

Comment: It isn't possible to give an answer based on what you have said. If you want to create an error log then create an error log. You don't need anybody's approval to do so.

Comment: Are you referring to exceptions in general, or a specific programming language?

Comment: I am working with C#. I am just looking for recommended practices.